# splitting the String using StringTokenizer in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I have recently started learning Java. I got stuck on Splitting the particular string. Here is the string:

```
String head = "(*, grandparent(X,Y))";
```

I want to split the string such that it will give two tokens. The two tokens should be * and  `grandparent(X,Y)`. I have tried to split it by

```
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(head,",");
System.out.println("The tokens are: " + st.countTokens());
```

But I am getting three tokens if I split it by comma.

I don't want to split it by regex. Could you guys please help me?

Comment: If you always have 2 tokens you can specify the limit for number of tokens generated with [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

Comment: Short answer based on title: *Don't.* Longer answer: Don't use [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). As the javadoc has been saying since Java 1.4: *`StringTokenizer` is a **legacy class** that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the java.util.regex package instead.*

Comment: Well, you are kinda supposed to get 3 strings if you split on `,`, no?

Comment: and split takes parameters. which might be useful :). EDIT: Oops @Chris beat me to it :p

Comment: I realized my comment should be an answer... Expanded on it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always have 2 tokens you can specify the limit for number of tokens generated with [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

For example: `String[] tokens = head.split(",", 2)`

Please don't use StringTokenizer in new code, its usage has been discouraged for a while in favor of newer better ways of doing similar work.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the first comma using `indexOf(',')`.

Example:

```
String head="(*, grandparent(X,Y))";

int idx = head.indexOf(',');

String sub1 = head.substring(1, idx);
String sub2 = head.substring(idx + 1, head.length() - 1);

System.out.println("sub1 = " + sub1);
System.out.println("sub2 = " + sub2);
```

Comment: Pretty Useful! Thanks Zack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) from [guava](https://github.com/google/guava) as following:

```
String head="(*, grandparent(X,Y))";

Iterable<String> tokens = Splitter.on(",").limit(2).split(head);

for(String token : tokens){
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

Below the maven dependency to add to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi I suggest to try this piece of code.
It's a hack that works, depending on the content of the head string.
For the shared value of head, it will work.

```
head=head.replace("*,","*;");
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(head,";");
```

Good luck

Comment: This really doesn't look like good style; quite a tacky hack.

Comment: @Debosmit Ray I agree it's a hack.